# A die is thrown five times, what is the probability that you get 20 as the sum of the values

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

This is supposed to be a Inclusion-Exclusion problem.

We have $6^5=7776$ different results.

Now, with the Inclusion-Exclusion principle i resolve the number of solutions for the equation:

$d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4+d_5=20  , 1 \leq d_i \leq 6 ,\forall 1 \leq i \leq 5$

That, i think, is equivalent to resolve:

$d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4+d_5=15  , 0 \leq d_i \leq 5 ,\forall 1 \leq i \leq 5$

This is:

$\binom{19}{15}-\binom{5}{1} \binom{13}{9}+\binom{5}{2} \binom{7}{3}=651$

So mi answer is: $\frac{651}{7776}$.

However, the "correct answer" is: $\frac{116}{7776}$. Whats the problem with mi reasoning?

**EDIT**
I found the solutions for my problem in the book, the result is: $\frac{651}{7776}$.

I was right, but the solution from mi teacher was wrong. Thats why the confusion.

Comment: You probably mean $6^5$ different results?

Comment: @gt6989b Yes, my mistake.

Comment: How do you get that expression that evaluates to $651$?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Trying to simplifiy the original equation. I assign one element to the five variables, an then decrease the right side: $20-5=15$

Comment: @ShreevatsaR http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cbinom%7B19%7D%7B15%7D-%5Cbinom%7B5%7D%7B1%7D*+%5Cbinom%7B13%7D%7B9%7D%2B%5Cbinom%7B5%7D%7B2%7D+*%5Cbinom%7B7%7D%7B3%7D shows this evaluates to 651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate this by finding the coefficient on $x^{20}$ in the polynomial
$$
\left(\frac{1}{6}x+\frac{1}{6}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{6}x^4+\frac{1}{6}x^5+\frac{1}{6}x^6 \right)^5
$$
Using PARI/GP, I get that this polynomial is $$\frac{1}{7776} x^{30}
 + \frac{5}{7776} x^{29}
 + \frac{5}{2592} x^{28}
 + \frac{35}{7776} x^{27}
 + \frac{35}{3888} x^{26}
 + \frac{7}{432} x^{25}
 + \frac{205}{7776} x^{24}
 + \frac{305}{7776} x^{23}
 + \frac{35}{648} x^{22}
 + \frac{5}{72} x^{21}
 + \frac{217}{2592} x^{20}
 + \frac{245}{2592} x^{19}
 + \frac{65}{648} x^{18}
 + \frac{65}{648} x^{17}
 + \frac{245}{2592} x^{16}
 + \frac{217}{2592} x^{15}
 + \frac{5}{72} x^{14}
 + \frac{35}{648} x^{13}
 + \frac{305}{7776} x^{12}
 + \frac{205}{7776} x^{11}
 + \frac{7}{432} x^{10}
 + \frac{35}{3888} x^9
 + \frac{35}{7776} x^8
 + \frac{5}{2592} x^7
 + \frac{5}{7776} x^6
 + \frac{1}{7776} x^5
$$
This shows that your value, $\frac{651}{7776}=\frac{217}{2592}$ is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im going to accept it. I have recently find the solution in the book, and i was right.

Answer (score 5):

Using generating functions, we get a generating function of
$$f(x) = 1+x+\ldots+x^5 = \frac{1-x^6}{1-x}$$
for each variable so we are now looking for the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $f(x)^5$:
$$
\begin{split}
\left[x^{15}\right]\frac{\left(1-x^6\right)^5}{(1-x)^5}
  &= \left[x^{15}\right]\frac{1-5x^6+10x^{12}}{(1-x)^5} \\
  &= \left[ \left[x^{15}\right] -5\left[x^{9}\right] + 10 \left[x^{3}\right]\right]
     \frac{1}{(1-x)^5}\\
  &= 3876 - 5 \cdot 715 + 10 \cdot 35 \\
  &= 651.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: I dont know what are generating functions. And what means 336?

Comment: $336$ would be the numerator for your probability fraction.

Comment: @JohnHabert Well, is very far from the supposed solution.

Comment: @Wyvern666 I'm not making any claim as to the accuracy of the method. I'm just answering your question about what the $336$ means. If I could answer accurately myself, I would. I leave it to those with more knowledge.

Comment: @JohnHabert I know, thanks.

Comment: I believe you'e got the expansion of $(1 - x)^{-5} = \sum_k \binom{-5}{k} x^k = \sum_k  \binom{4 + k}{4} x^k$ wrong. Other than that glitch, very nice appoach.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland no. i am solving the second problem. your approach should look for the coefficient of $x^20$, which is equivalent - $x^5$ cancels out...

Comment: @vonbrand actually checked the expansion, your coefficients come out the same, $\binom{19}{4} = 3876, \binom{13}{4} = 715, \binom{7}{4} = 35$. Wolfram Alpha doesn't lie :)